# Vue removing elements when using new Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I've been experimenting with Vue and I wanted to be able to have a function run on a button press.

I've tried using ids instead of classes, but it didn't seem to work (nothing happened on button press); it seems like it isn't actually selecting the button.

Button:
`<a class="button is-rounded is-medium vb" v-on:click="next1">Lets get started.</a>`

JS:

```
var button = new Vue({
    el: '.vb',
    methods: {
        next1: function() {
            alert("pressed!")
        }
    }
  })
```

When I go to the page, the button is gone and in devtools it shows that it gets replaced with `<!---->`.

Comment: Is this all code you have or is there more? Your code should just be working as in here: https://jsfiddle.net/dreijntjens/tpg3u5mr/2/

Comment: dreijntjens, there is more, but even when removing everything except this line and  vue it still happens.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the template to the vue instance.

```
var button = new Vue({
    el: '#vb',
    methods: {
        next1: function() {
            alert("pressed!")
        }
    },
    template: `
        <a class="button is-rounded is-medium" v-on:click="next1">Lets get started.</a>
    `
  })
```

And the element you are mounting to should be simply:

```html
<div id="#vb"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a little weird but I managed to get it working.

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self';" />` was stopping it from working. Removing that line makes it work perfectly. Thanks for your suggestions though :)